# React Infinite Loop Causes State to Freeze

Tags: reactjs, authentication, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a react amplify project for which I've just added Cognito. When not logged into the site, (i.e. in guest mode) I am able to call the API, however when I am logged in it only calls once on page load. When I try to trigger it manually it makes the API call, then everything freezes and the page goes unresponsive.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const getArticlesOnceUE = async() => {
            console.log("Calling the API")
            var arts = await atlasAPI.getCountryNews(selectedCountry, null) // This line runs and cloudwatch indicates the lambda finishes.
            console.log("Getting Data from Response") // This line doesn't run
            var articleData = arts.data
            console.log("Sorting Articles")
            const sorted_arts_r = articleData.sort((a,b) => b.datetime-a.datetime)
            const seper_arts = seperateArticles(sorted_arts, 30)
            console.log(seper_arts)
            setArticles(seper_arts)
        }
    
        getArticlesOnceUE()
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [selectedCountry]);
```

The code above is where the code fails when `selectedCountry` is updated the comments show where the issue is. The code below is the API code that is called.

```js
async function GetCountryNews(country) {
        try {
            const apiName = "AtlasAPI";
            const path = "/get-country-news/";

            const data = { 
                body: {
                    "country": country
                } 
            };

            console.log("Before POST") // This runs
            const res = await API.post(apiName, path, data);
            console.log("After POST") // This does not run

            return res
        } catch(error) {
            console.log("Error calling API: ", error);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In cloudwatch every print statement up to the return runs, but the data never comes back to the react app. Is this a common issue? What are some potential solutions.

EDIT:

**Apparently it's not just the API. If I call anything that sets state the app, or at least react, seems to crash.**

EDIT 2:

**I changed the name to reflect what I've learned. An infinite re-render that react didn't catch caused the app to freeze continuously.**

Comment: Why aren't you using the native functionality provided by AWS Amplify by doing `amplify add api` in the `CLI`? You can use permissions with graphql then.

Comment: @Luke I am using that functionality. As I've added above, I missed an infinite rerender because I forgot to supply a useEffect hook with a dependency array.

Comment: Add your answer in the answer box below?